# Flutter Error: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I got this error when I run my first flutter app in android studio. my emulator internet is connected and the airplane mode is off. I saw other similar question but none of them were like this error and they didn't help me. can anyone help me?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Could not resolve compiler classpath. Check if Kotlin Gradle plugin repository is configured in project ':app'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlinCompilerClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.50.
     Required by:
         project :app > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.50 > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.50.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.50.
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
...
```

if more details are required please tell me. thanks.

Comment: have you tried running `flutter doctor --android-licenses` ? check if any warnings shows up. if it does, accepting all licenses might fix the problem.

Comment: @MichaelSoliman yes I tried this and everything is ok, there is no warning! :(

Answer (score 2):

this is happen to me several times

have you try to build the gradle

1. cd android
2. ./gradlew build

it will show the error more detail

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.